# Isn't java bytecode executes sequentially?

Tags: java, static-members

i am expecting following code to print lines before the statement in which static variable value is set, but it is not working as expected.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
class Bank{
private static boolean isInCrisis = false;
public static boolean getIsInCrisis(){return Bank.isInCrisis;}
public static boolean setIsInCrisis(boolean crisis){
    return Bank.isInCrisis = crisis; 
}
public String getCash() throws Exception{
    if(!Bank.isInCrisis){
        return new String("$100"); 
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("Bank is in crisis"); 
    }
}
}

public class InstanceObjects{
public static void main(String... st) {
    try{
        Bank hsbc = new Bank();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        hsbc.setIsInCrisis(true);
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());            
        writer.close(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
}
```

output is throwing the exception "Bank is in crisis", but it should first print some lines of "collect cash ..." message and then the throwed exception message...

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace and indicate the statement in `main()` where the exception is thrown (should be the second `at` line).

Comment: @mabbas , and what about printf statements just above `hsbc.setIsInCrisis(true)`? output should be like: collect cash $100,...., exception is caught .... bank is in crisis ...

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Bank is in crisis
 at Bank.getCash(InstanceObjects.java:13)
 at InstanceObjects.main(InstanceObjects.java:31)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `PrintWriter` is never being flushed. It's accumulating data, but it never writes it to the console because the exception is thrown before its buffer is full.

If you call `writer.flush()` before the call that throws the exception, you'll see the expected messages.

If you close the writer in a finally block you'll see the data when it's closed, as that flushes the writer too... but *after* the exception, as `catch` is executed before `finally`.

If you use a `try-with-resources` block instead, you'll see the data *before* the exception, because there the `close` happens in a "nested" try/finally, effectively:

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out)) {
    Bank hsbc = new Bank();
    ...
} catch(Exception e){
    // writer will already be closed here
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

`writer.flush();`

The `printf` method does not auto flush, your messages are sitting in a buffer that is never sent to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the stream before getting to the message that throws the exception.

```
public class Main{ public static void main(String... st) {
    try{
        Bank hsbc = new Bank();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());
        writer.flush();
        hsbc.setIsInCrisis(true);
        writer.printf("collect cash: %s\n",hsbc.getCash());            
        writer.close(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } } }
```

Prints:

```
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
collect cash: $100
java.lang.Exception: Bank is in crisis
    at Bank.getCash(Main.java:13)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```